# CSS Scrolling Menu

Tags: css

The following code creates  a page where the submenu is hidden. I'm looking to show it up while the mouse hovers the
main menu's caption and fail to do so.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">;
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">;
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255" />
<style type="text/css">
    #menu ul > #menu1 ul
  {
   display:none;
 }

#menu ul li a:hover 
          {
           #menu ul > #menu1 ul{display:block;}
          }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">abc</a>
            <ul>
<div id="menu1">    
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a data-href="#">3</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                    </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Can anyone show me please where have i gone wrong in that code ? How can i show the submenu when "abc" is hovered?
Thanks a lot

Comment: FWIW, http://jsfiddle.net/ is a great site for constructing a demonstration of questions like this one

Comment: dear see my answer and let me know if any issues or i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the fiddle and demo:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rYaM3/3/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rYaM3/3/embedded/result/

SS:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dinesh. Sorry for the delay, I only now connected.

Comment: its ok dear no problem and please dont say sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot nest CSS blocks

What you can do, however, is have a `div` inside your `li` and use CSS to apply styles to the `div` only when there is a hover on the `li`

Notice `#menu ul li:hover div` in the code below. The `div` is subjected to the style only on an `li:hover` This trick should help you get the menu effect you are looking for

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255" />
  <style type="text/css">
    #menu ul li div
    {
      display:none
    }

    #menu ul li:hover div
    {
      display: block
    }
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">abc</a>
            <div id="menu1">    
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a data-href="#">3</a></li>
              </ul> 
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

demo on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f2kp2/1/

Comment: Hi Elvis,Thanks a lot for your answer which resembles that of Dinesh that came first so  selected it as "The Answer" but yours is as enlightening.